# Alamofire Invalid value around character 0 | Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode10

So i am repetitively getting this error:

> "Invalid value around character 0."

I have exhausted all avenues in debugging this. Basically the API is working fine in Postman but is failing horribly through code. The Postman is locally setup hence i cannot share it here. Anyhow, this is my code:

```
        let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                       "Accept": "application/json"]
        let params = ["userId":"98", "candidateId":"4"]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding:
            JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).response { response in

                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any]
                        completion(json , nil)
                    } catch {
                        completion(nil, response.error)
                    }
                }else{
                    completion(nil, response.error)
                }
        }
```

Ive tried responseString, responseJSON & response and JSONSerialization I've used options with .allowFragments, .mutableContainers & .mutableLeaves but no use. I've even tried giving it headers although the Postman call doesn't include headers but again failing terribly. What should i do, please help. Below is a snapshot of response object:

[image]

This is the [responseString](https://jpst.it/1sR2x) im getting after I do this:

```
String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

& this is the Error when i remove .allowFragments:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

POSTMAN CALL SNAPSHOT:

[image]

Comment: send headers `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept-Type: application/json`

Comment: I did but to no avail

Comment: Print `reponseString` and check if it's really JSON or if you are not missing a param/header.

Comment: What does `responseString` gets?

Comment: I have updated the code with these suggestions but still nothing, the params and headers are alright and the url is perfectly well, the Postman is sending proper result, why can't i see it here

Comment: post response from Postman, please

Comment: Again, what's the `responseString` (or `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` ? Also, `.mutableContainers` & `.mutableLeaves` shouldn't be used in Swift. If you use `String`, Swift Array of Swift Dictionary, they are already mutable. And `.allowFragments` is to validate a specific JSON: single `String` (when top level is a String, and not an Array/Dictionary).

Comment: @Larme Ive added whats required

Comment: Your response is HTML, not JSON.

Comment: @Larme yeah but how come its working on Postman? And its working on Android as well

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko please see the postman snapshot. Thanks

Comment: With POSTMAN, you can generate Swift Code. You can check what's the header that it puts (some are "implicit"), and compare with yours.

Comment: EVERYONE! IT WAS A URL PROBLEM, THE SERVER GUY PROVIDED ME WITH CRAP URL   x[ Thank you though for all the help and I am sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your headers

```
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept-Type": "application/json"]
```

`Accept-Type` is not a valid HTTP header. What you need is `Accept`

```
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                     "Accept": "application/json"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

Changing content-type header from

```
 headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Token"
    ]
```

To

```
 headers    = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization" : "Token"
        ]
```

Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the question has been posted a long time ago, but I've just faced this issue early. So I'm gonna leave some solution that I hope may help someone who faces this error.

I'll list some solutions that can fix the error:

1. **Check Header and Identify the response from the server**

This one might cause trouble to make this error occure, because sometime server response **json**, **xml** or just **x-www-form-urlencoded** so you've to look closely at the response type and we've to create header to match those types.

**For example:**

[JSON Data]
`let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]`

[x-www-form-urlencoded]
`let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"]`

2. this one is really simple and tricky and it's your **endpoint** sometimes we missed this place, invalid or missing endpoint can also occur this error, and in my case, I missed this point.

Well, I hope this little information can help someone who faces the same problem as me, cheer.